# input/output validation/casting of a numpy calculation

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, sanitization

This is a situation that happens quite often in my codes. Say I have a function `do_sth(a,b)`, that, only for the sake of this example, simply calculates `a+b`, with `a,b` either 1D `numpy` arrays or scalars. In many occasions, I need the function to broadcast the operation, so that if both `a,b` are 1D arrays, the result will be a 2D array. An example of what I mean follows:

```
do_sth(1,2) -> 3
do_sth([1,2],0) -> array([1, 2])
do_sth(0,[3,4]) -> array([3, 4])
do_sth([1,2],[3,4]) -> array([[4, 5], [5, 6]])
```

This is a bit similar to how a numpy `ufunc` behaves. A possible implementation follows:

```
from numpy import newaxis, atleast_1d

def do_sth(a, b):
    "a,b should be either 1d numpy arrays or scalars"
    a, b = map(atleast_1d, [a, b])
    # the line below mocks a more complicated calculation
    res = a[:, newaxis] + b[newaxis]

    conds = [a.size == 1, b.size == 1]

    if all(conds):
        return res[0, 0]
    elif any(conds):
        return res.ravel()
    else:
        return res
```

As you can see, there's quite a lot of boilerplate. The first question is: is this the right way to do this input/output casting? Is there any reason to not use a decorator to deal with a situation like this? Is there any guideline on the matter?

Moreover, the more complicated calculation, here mocked by the addition, often fails badly if `a` or `b` are numpy arrays with 2D,3D shape for example. I say badly in the sense that the point where the calculation fails is not obvious, or may change with time in different revisions of the code, and it is hard to see the connection between the error and the wrong input shape. I think it is then NOT advisable to put the complicated calculation in a `try/except` block (following python [EAFP](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-eafp)). In this case, is it correct to check the shape of the 2 arrays at the beginning of the function? Is there any alternative? Is there a numpy function that allows at the same time to convert the input to a numpy array, and also check that the input is compatible with a certain number of dimensions, something like `asarray_withdim(arr,ndim=5)`?

Comment: ufuncs have an `outer` method - your function `do_sth(a, b)` seems to be exactly `np.add.outer(a, b)` for example. I'm not sure if this fully addresses your question though.

Comment: Non complied `numpy` functions often have a lot of code that massages the inputs into convenient dimensions. Then they do the core action, followed by final reshaping and type wrapping.  They might use functions like `np.atleast_2d` to ensure there are enough dimensions, and `.reshape(-1,1,1)` to compress excess dimensions.

Comment: @ajcr, thanks for looking into this, but here the addition is a trivial example. In my code I am doing a more complicated calculation.

Comment: @hpaulj, thanks for sharing. Looking at the code, for example [here](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.9.1/numpy/core/numeric.py), it is standard in numpy to first massage the input, check the input and raise exceptions first. This answers more or less the 2nd question, and you could post it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the use of decorators - I haven't seen much use of decorators in `numpy` code, but I think that's because most of the functionality was developed before decorators become common in Python.  If you can make it work, there shouldn't be a any downside (but I'm not an expert with either decorators or `ufunc`).

Non complied numpy functions often have a lot of code that massages the inputs into convenient dimensions. Then they do the core action, followed by final reshaping and type wrapping. They might use functions like np.atleast_2d to ensure there are enough dimensions, and .reshape(-1,1,1) to compress excess dimensions.

`np.tensordot` is an example of one that performs axes transpose plus reshape on the inputs so it can apply the compiled `np.dot`.  `np.insert` starts with a number of `ndim` and `isinstance` tests.  Special cases are handled early, while the general one is left to the end.  `np.einsum` is compiled, but there's a lot of preprocessing being done in C code, before it finally creates an `nditer` object and does the calculation.